# calculating every next month of a given date using php

Tags: php, date, fullcalendar, recurrence

I want some help about calculating every next month  of a given date  from the first date of each month

for example :

the event date is: '2019-07-15' then if the start date is: 2019-08-01
the output is : 
2019-08-15

---

the event date is: '2019-07-15' then if the start date is: 2019-09-01
the output is : 
2019-09-15

---

the event date is: '2019-07-15' then if the start date is: 2019-10-01
the output is : 
2019-10-15

Comment: Why don't you just add 1 month to the event date ?

Comment: You have to get the start date, add one month and then in the output you have to change the day to the one in event date. That's it ?

Comment: I'm working with a fullcalendar plugin 
so  I need to repeat that  event every month from that first day of every month  
if i just add 1 month to that event date it will be not showing on my calendar

Comment: @Alexis  yes exactly

Comment: use nesbot/carbon to easy date manipulating

Comment: If you are using the latest fullCalendar (version 4 - and you really should be using it if you can), it supports [recurring events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events) - so just specify the start date of your event, and then specify the frequency of recurrence. No need to do any calculations yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution. I hope it works for you :

```
<?php
$event_date = "2019-07-15";
$event_month = date('m', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($event_date)));
$start_date = date("Y-".$event_month."-01", strtotime($event_date));
$output_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($event_date))); 

echo $event_date."<br>";
echo $start_date."<br>";
echo $output_date."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: The question is about causing the event to recur repeatedly, not just incrementing by a single month